# Android return from fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment, back-button

I have got an activity with two fragments: FragmentA and FragmentB. In FragmentB is a button which should ensure return back to fragmentA, however still cannot figure out how to do that :( As it's not an activity, I am unable to use onBackPressed(). Any suggestions ? 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to go back to the last fragment, every time you add, replace a fragment you should also add `transaction.addToBackStack(null);` which will add the fragment to the backstack so every time you click the backbutton the last fragment is loaded and the current fragment is destroy.

**example:**

```
FragmentTransaction transaction = activity.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.addToBackStack(null);
    transaction.replace(YOU_LAYOUT, YOUR FRAGMENT, null).commit();
```

**sample:**

```
Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.YOUR_ID);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                  YOURFRAGMENTCLASSNAME.getActivity().onBackPressed();
            }
        });
```

**YOURFRAGMENTCLASSNAME.getActivity().onBackPressed();** will call the activity's onbackpressed method.

Comment: Thanks for reply, yeah I got that, however, I wanted to create a button which would behave as "hardware" back button. But, as it's fragment, I am unable to use onBackPressed() :(